# Is it impossible to write thread code in Rust?

Tags: rust, virtual-machine

I was reading about [the Erlang BEAM virtual machine](https://blog.stenmans.org/theBeamBook/#CH-BEAM) which uses a technique confusingly called [direct threaded code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threaded_code) to efficiently dispatch VM operations. As I understand it, it relies on the availability of unrestricted jump statements in the host C language to dynamically arrange program flow during interpretation. Does that mean that the technique is impossible to use in Rust, or is there an escape hatch?

Comment: Jumps are not impossible in Rust, but you will probably need to use inline asm. I’d recommend just to write usual multithreaded code using [`std::thread`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/). There is no virtual machine in Rust by the way.

Comment: @Miiao This is not related to threads. And yes, as far as I can tell, C's extension "label as values" is not available in Rust, although I think there were discussions about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rust uses structured control flow. This means there are no `goto`s or similar construct.

To allow unstructured control flow to be represented in a structured language such as Rust, transpilers for WASM (C -> WASM) or in [C2Rust](https://github.com/immunant/c2rust) (C -> Rust), an algorithm called Relooper can be used, which represents unstructured control flow as a finite state machine. Read more in ["Why Do We Need the Relooper Algorithm, Again?"](http://troubles.md/why-do-we-need-the-relooper-algorithm-again/)

The Relooper algorithm was originally developed for Emscripten (a precursor to WASM), and has a white paper here describing it: [Emscripten: An LLVM-to-JavaScript Compiler (PDF)](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/main/docs/paper.pdf).  See section 3.2 on the Relooper, which begins:

> The Relooper the most complex module in Emscripten. It
> receives a ‘soup of blocks’, which is a set of labeled frag-
> ments of code, each ending with a branch operation, and the
> goal is to generate normal high-level JavaScript code flow
> structures such as loops and ifs.

Comment: I interpret this answer as "yes", but I guess I'll go and read the code of some Rust VMs. Thanks!